# facebook javascript is not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I asked this question before also but I didnt got any solution. 
    I am facing problem from my website where facebook install on the totally right side of the page and will move and show when mouse over it. Please [spammy link removed] to see it.

The problem is when I mouse over it one time its showing and again if i mouse over two or three times its not showing anything. Sometimes even in the first mouse over also will not show anything.

I want to make it like another website [spammy link removed], where it will show again and agian and there is no problem.

My html code is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div id="facebook_tab">
    <a id="facebooklink" href="https://www.facebook.com/fe driksa" title="Fe dri on Facebook" onmouseover="document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'block';this.style.display='none';"></a>
    <div id="showme" onmouseout="document.getElementById('facebooklink').style.display='block';this.style.display='none';">
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fe driksa" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css code is

```
#facebook_tab
{
    display: block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 102px;
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/facebook_tab.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    right:0px;
    top:200px;
    position:fixed;
}

#facebook_tab span
{
    display: none;
}

#facebook_tab:hover {
width:292px;
padding-left:32px;
}

#facebook_tab:hover span
{
    display:block;
background-color:#fff;
border:2px solid #999;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: We are not going to visit your website to help you troubleshoot an issue.  Provide a minimal demonstration of the troublesome code *here*.

Comment: I found and I have added the code, can u suggest me now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done totally with css (except the loading of the facebook content).

even the smooth animation should be done with [css transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

html and loading of facebook like box:

```
<div id="facebook-wrapper">
  <a id="facebooklink" href="https://www.facebook.com/fedriksa" title="Fedri on Facebook"></a>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
</div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

your css:

```
#facebook-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 220px; // put the width of your facebook box + width of your facebook link here
  right: -200px; // this should be the width of your facebook box
}

#facebook-wrapper:hover {
  right: 0
  transition: right 2s;
  -moz-transition: right 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: right 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: right 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

note, this is untested, but should give you an idea about how to do this!

Comment: hi hereandnow, please can u explain me. I dont know more codes. What should I add in this codes you have provided. And, thanks you very much for your reply.. what I have to add in wrapper:hover ?? for firefox and other browers

Comment: just put the first part of your code into your html, the second part inside your css, and go from there.

Comment: can you please check my code, I have added in my question. If you can give me some solution.

Comment: you dont need the onmouseout-stuff in your showme-div! put the link of your site to see what is going wrong

Comment: i'll say it one last time. remove this 'onmouseover="document...' and all the other inline javascript from all your elements that are inside your facebook_tab. otherwise i cant help you.